# ReactJS, import files within render()

Tags: reactjs

I need to import some files (PDFs in this case, but also SVGs later) into an `<embed>` element. I am iterating over a list of props that send me the path to the PDF. When imported at the head of the component, and injected everything works fine as expected. However, I need to dynamically set these paths, and I know I cannot import inside render. Using the paths themselves gives me no result.

Does not work:

```
// pdf.src = './path/to/file.pdf'
{project.projectPDFs.map((pdf, index) =>
    <embed className="pdf-viewer" src={pdf.src} width="100%" key={index} />
    )
}
```

Works:

```
import PDF from './path/to/file.pdf';
{project.projectPDFs.map((pdf, index) =>
    <embed className="pdf-viewer" src={PDF} width="100%" key={index} />
    )
}
```

App is bootstrapped with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which does have the url-loader, but not sure what else is going on under the hood.

Comment: Did you try to put the direct path in state? Then you can do `src={this.state.pdf.src}`

Answer (score 0):

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is using the `Webpack` to build your app. So the URL of your file will be changed after built.

`import  PDF from './path/to/file.pdf';`
will change your file path into another hashed string and stored into `PDF`. So you will have no error in a second way.

In your case, you have two ways to do:

1. Import all resources first

   ```
   import PDF1 from '/path/to/PDF1';
   import PDF2 from '/path/to/PDF2';
   import PDF3 from '/path/to/PDF3';
   import PDF4 from '/path/to/PDF4';
   const pdfs = {PDF1, PDF2, PDF3, PDF4};
   ...
   {project.projectPDFs.map((pdf, index) => (
       <embed className="pdf-viewer" src={pdfs[pdf]} width="100%" key={index} />
   )}
   ```
2. Dynamic import

   ```
   const embeds = await Promise.all(project.projectPDFs.map(async (pdf, index) => {
       const pdfPath = await import(pdf);
       return (<embed className="pdf-viewer" src={pdfPath} width="100%" key={index} />);
   }));
   ```